# main.CRITICAL: DomainException: $_FILES array is empty in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:687

Tags: magento2.4.5, system.log

Getting this error consistently in system.log - on Magento 2.4.5-p1...

```
[2023-02-22T19:34:48.304327+00:00] main.CRITICAL: DomainException: $_FILES array is empty in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:687
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php(230): Magento\Framework\File\Uploader->_setUploadFileId('product[product...')
#1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Model/File/Uploader.php(67): Magento\Framework\File\Uploader->__construct('product[product...')
#2 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Model/File/Uploader/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader->__construct('product[product...', Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension))
#3 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader\Interceptor->__construct('product[product...', Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension))
#4 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\MediaSt...', Array)
#5 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\MediaSt...', Array)
#6 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Model/File/UploaderFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\MediaS...', Array)
#7 /srv/public_html/vendor/sparsh/magento-2-product-label-extension/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/File.php(93): Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory->create(Array)
#8 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Sparsh/ProductLabel/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/File/Interceptor.php(23): Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\File->afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#9 [internal function]: Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\File\Interceptor->afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#10 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(682): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1848): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array)
#12 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(327): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->_afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#13 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1966): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->_afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#14 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(33): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#15 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#16 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#17 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#18 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#19 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(50): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#20 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(110): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#21 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(106): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#22 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(777): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#23 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#24 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#25 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#26 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(28): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#27 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#28 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#29 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(28): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#30 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#31 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#32 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#33 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php(886): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#34 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php(634): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->saveProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#35 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#36 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#37 /srv/public_html/vendor/prince/module-productattachment/Plugin/ProductAttachment.php(147): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#38 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Mageprince\Productattach\Plugin\ProductAttachment->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), false)
#39 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#40 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#41 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductWebsiteLinkRepository.php(40): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#42 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductWebsiteLinkRepository->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductWebsiteLink))
#43 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(195): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#45 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#47 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#49 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#51 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#52 /srv/public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#53 {main} [] []
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Do you see this error if you disable Sparsh_ProductLabel extension?
Were you getting this error on an older version? Did it start happening after Magento upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: Please use enctype'=>'multipart/form-data